# Select2 Changing Data progamatically

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-select2

I am attempting to programmatically change the dataset in a select2 dropdown when I change the value of another select2 dropdown.

The issue I am having is weird, as it seems to change the badge values but not the options themselves. You can see the 2 and 3 in badge but the values for the text in one dataset are completely different but it's not changing the options.

This is a fiddle to show what I mean. https://jsfiddle.net/jamiebrs/8axy7123/

This is the `formatText` function:

```
function formatText (icon) {
  if(icon.badge == undefined){
    return  $('<span>' + icon.text + '</span>');
  } else {
    return  $('<span><span class="badge">'+ icon.badge + '</span> ' + icon.text + '</span>');
  }
}
```

This is the event that is trying to trigger changing the options of the `#products` dropdown when a `#fam` option is selected. The `eval(d)` call takes the selected value and retrieves a corresponding variable I have defined that contains the proper options for `#products`.

```
$('#fam').select2().on('change', function() {
  d = $(this).val();

  $('#products').val(null).trigger('change');
  $('#products').select2({
    data: eval(d),
    width: "100%",
    theme: 'bootstrap4',
    placeholder: "Select item",
    allowClear: true,
    templateSelection: formatText,
    templateResult: formatText
  }).trigger('change');
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple issues that you need to address. First of all, once a select2 is initialized with data, it will keep all of its options. Your code that calls this:

```
$('#products').val(null).trigger('change')
```

does not empty the options from the drop-down list, it simply de-selects any options that were already selected (so if you had selected 'enhancement' and 'bug', it would have de-selected those). I assume you looked at the [Clearing Selections](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items#clearing-selections) section of the [select2 documentation](https://select2.org/) and assumed it emptied the options.

What you need to do is completely clear all of the options, destroy the select2 instance, and then re-initialize it with the proper data, which would look like this:

```
$('#products').empty().select('destroy').select2({/* your options here */});
```

I noticed in your question and fiddle a few things that I would suggest you alter:

1. Move your `#products` config into a variable so you can reuse and override it
2. Put your `#products` options into an object keyed by corresponding `#fam` option values, so that you can retrieve the proper options from that object instead of calling `eval()` which is [dangerous and should not be used](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Never_use_eval!).

Your code would then look like this:

```
const productOptions = {data1: [/*...*/], data2: [/*...*/]};
const productsConfig = {
  width: "100%",
  theme: 'bootstrap4',
  placeholder: "Select item",
  allowClear: true,
  templateSelection: formatText,
  templateResult: formatText
};

$('#fam').select2().on('change', function() {
  // get selected value from the #fam select2
  const selected = $(this).val();

  // get the new products config (products config + data options)
  const newProductsConfig = Object.assign({},
    productsConfig,
    {data: productOptions[selected]}
  );

  // destroy the existing products select2 and re-initialize
  $('#products').empty().select2('destroy').select2(newProductsConfig);
});
```

Then when you initially load your page, you can use the products config to initialize it, and then initialize the fam select2 while triggering the `.change()` event to automatically populate the products options:

```
// initialize the products select2 on page load
$('#products').select2(productsConfig);

// initialize the fam select2 and trigger the change event
// which will properly populate products options with whatever
// fam option is currently selected on page load
$('#fam').select2({
  theme: 'bootstrap4', 
  placeholder: "Select item",
  width: "100%"
}).change();
```

Comment: Thank you. I redid the fiddle based on your suggestions and got the functionality working but am getting some weirdness in how the #fam select is displaying in that it is not showing 100% on the width and adding in a pixel width?

The fiddle is updated.

Comment: You're calling `$('#fam').select2().on('change'` instead of `$('#fam').on('change'` which is accidentally initializing select2 on `#fam` without the configuration you specified, which is causing that issue.